# VB.net display in textbox multiple values names with separate comma

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I would like to ask.

I have a textEdit that accepts all values from xtragridview selected column. My problem is it ends with comma.

Currently have this output:

textEdit: Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4,

Expected output goes like this:

textEdit: Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4

I used this code:

```
For i = 0 To GridView1.RowCount - 1
   textEdit1.Text += GridView1.Columns.View.GetRowCellValue(i, "Names") + (", ")
Next
```

I need help that who can modified my code. I will be thankful. ^_^

Comment: Make a new list of string and in the loop add desired values to the list. Then join the list.toarray with ',' .

Comment: Please put some thought into your tags in future. This has nothing to do with VBA, VS or the WinForms designer. Don't try to trick people into reading your question when it's irrelevant to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using list of string and join :

```
DIM s AS NEW LIST (of string)
For i = 0 To GridView1.RowCount - 1
   s.add( GridView1.Columns.View.GetRowCellValue(i, "Names") )
Next
textEdit1.Text = JOIN(s.toarray , ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
For i = 0 To GridView1.RowCount - 1
   textEdit1.Text += GridView1.Columns.View.GetRowCellValue(i, "Names") + (", ")
Next
textEdit1.Text = Left(textEdit1.Text,Len(textEdit1.Text)-2) '-2 for trailing space
```

Or

```
For i = 0 To GridView1.RowCount - 1
   textEdit1.Text += GridView1.Columns.View.GetRowCellValue(i, "Names") & IFF(i = GridView1.RowCount -1,"",", ")
Next
```

Let me know if something's wrong, I'm not familiar with gridview but I assumed "&" still works and you don't need to encapsulate it in brackets.